# PayPal trial period after recurring payment has started

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, recurring

Client wants to take PayPal subscription to an online service 1 month before the service launches (pre-sales push).

Client then wants the subsequent recurring payment to start 1 month after service launch (because the customer has already "paid" for the first month in advance).

e.g. customer pays monthly subscription on March 1.  Service launches next month on April 1, customer is not charged again until May 1.

Same goes for 6 monthly and annual subscriptions (shifting the next payment date for the subscription +1 month).

In Stripe I can set a trial period for a subscription after it has started for X days from the Stripe dashboard.

Q1: Can this be done in PayPal?
Q2 Can this be done manually by the client from the PayPal dashboard?